# Wordpress functions.php style version won't update

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this has been brought up a million times on here, but I have followed various solutions to no avail. My child theme stylesheet just won't change. It actually seems like any changes I make to the child functions.php don't take effect.

This is the closest post to my issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538578/wordpress-generatepress-theme-cache-busting) but the answer about cache busting hasn't worked for me. I am kind of thinking it has to do with how the parent theme enqueues child theme styles automatically, but I don't know how to override that.

functions.php styles enqueue:

```
// Load styles:
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'main_styles' );
function main_styles() {
  //* Bootstrap CSS
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

  //* Parent CSS
  wp_enqueue_style( 'corporate-plus',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

  //* Child theme CSS
  $cache_buster = date("YmdHi", filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'));
  wp_enqueue_style( 'yunev-corporate-plus',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( 'corporate-plus '),
    $cache_buster
  );
}
```

child theme style.css theme comments:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Yunev Custom
 Description:  Yunev Custom - Corporate Plus Child Theme
 Template:     corporate-plus
 Version:      1.1.2
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  yunevcorporatepluschild
*/
```

(I removed the author and such for this post)

I customized this child theme a while ago and the custom styles are working, but any changes I make now don't propagate. I have cleared cloudflare cache, cache plugin, everything I can think of. It's driving me crazy.

The child style version that I get in the browser is always '1.0.1'. Any troubleshooting tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to rename your stylesheet  or reupload your theme.